# Could not allow to take backup on akkeba backup in joomla 3.5.1

Tags: php, content-management-system, joomla3.5

[image]

Please see the above picture and help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you need to enable mbstring.

If you use cPanel and you have or can find out the username and password, this is done by logging in to cPanel at http://yourwebsite.com/cpanel (update the name to the url of your website obviously) and clicking on the "Select PHP Version" tool as shown below:

[image: php selector]

In the PHP Selector tool, enable mbstring by ticking the check box and clicking the Save button:

[image: enable mbstring]

Comment: In your hosting control panel which will look like the above if you are using cPanel and which you may find at websitename.com/cpanel or similar

Comment: yeah i m using cpanel ...but where the php selector is present

Comment: yeah understood....I m using Joomla cpanel  i think you are saying some other cpanel

Comment: Actually, cPanel is not specific to Joomla. Your cPanel may look a little different depending on the version. If it's a very old version, the PHP Selector tool may not be included.

Comment: If this is too hard, just log a support request with your hosting provider and they should be able to fix this.